# problème in installation of git

Tags: git, flutter

I have a problem during the installation of [Git for Widows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) in my Windows 10

```sh
unable to set system config 
"diff.astextplain.textconv":="astextplain": exit code 128

stderr:
fatal: open/dev/null or dup failed: No such file or directory
```

How can I get past this error?

Comment: What did you do and where did that appear?

Answer (score 0):

2023: [`git-for-windows/git` issue 4604](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4604) does propose [`git-for-windows/build-extra` PR 529](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/529) which should improve the installation process.

Try it with [Git for Windows v2.43.0-rc1.windows.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.43.0-rc1.windows.1)

---

2021: Check if, as in [issue 768](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/768#issuecomment-222241776), the Null service is running:

> The problem was that the Null service was not running on my machine and had to edit the registry to get it working properly again...

See also [issue 1016](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1016#issuecomment-274505686):

> This is not a problem of Git for Windows, but one of your setup.
> `NUL` is not expected to be disabled, like, ever, hence Git for Windows' installer does not try to do anything about it.
>
> I tried to find out what may have happened on your system (you will most likely run into more serious problems if you do not fix the issue that NUL cannot be found), but all I found was random (and rare) problems on Windows 7, not Windows 10.
>
> In my Windows 10 setup, there is a `%WINDOWS%\system32\drivers\null.sys` (which is the correct driver) and the registry key NUL in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices` is set to `\Device\Null`.
> Maybe something got messed up there in your setup.
>
> The following method through using .inf file fails, says the method is out of date:
> Beware: [That explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/installing-a-null-driver) how to install a NULL driver, not the NUL device driver (which is confusingly called the "`Null Device Driver`").